# GoogleUpdate.exe /ua switch, User account access?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, user-accounts, scheduled-tasks

I've noticed that after installing Google Chrome, two new Scheduled Tasks have appeared in my Windows 10 schtasks. One of them has the /tr of

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe /ua /installsource scheduler
```

Now as far as I know, to create an schtask without the user password, you probably need to create it under the SYSTEM user, and apparently, with Google Update this is the case.

**I have two questions:**

1) In the arguments of GoogleUpdate.exe, can we assume that /ua is an abbreviation of "User Account"?

2) If so, how can a task running under SYSTEM account, actually manipulate a user account without for example, LoadLibrary or CreateRemoteThread or RtlCreateUserThread. Or is that what Google does?

Answer (score 0):

No,

I believe (I can't find sources right now but it'd make sense) that the /ua switch is for 'unattended' as in "Don't ask the user before continuing"

Because of this, it also answers the 2nd part of your question - i.e. none of that is relevant.

Comment: I've also found people who say the /ua stands for update applications.